# Exporting Backbone.js Collection To Plain Text On Hard Disk & Importing Back

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I've been tinkering with Backbone.js for some time now.  I've been using localStorage for storing most of my app data.  I was wondering if would be possible for me to export my collection to a plain text and have it imported back again.  i.e I want to create a backup kind of feature where when the data is exported, an HTML textbox is displayed with the 'plain text' version of my collection and when I need to import back the data, I just paste it into an empty textbox and it re-creates the collection.

Is this possible, any tips on how to achieve this?  I was thinking about exporting it to JSON format and importing it back. Is that feasible?

p.s. I know there is no code here, but any idea would be much welcomed.

Comment: Sure, serializing it to JSON makes the most sense, and should be straightforward.  Just call `toJSON()` from the collection to export it, then `JSON.parse` and `collection.reset` to restore it.

Comment: Basically I've got a collection named Todos.  I've used the toJSON() methods of collections, but am uncertain as to whether it will cut it.

Comment: @dbaseman I tried to use toJSON, but it only returns an array of objects.  Outputting it to a textbox just shows a string like [object, object...].

Comment: Sorry, you also need to use JSON.stringify to convert the JSON to a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `toJSON` to serialize the collection.  (Actually [Backbone.js mentions this](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON) as a primary use for `collection.toJSON()`).  Use `JSON.stringify` to convert the JSON object to a string.

```
var json = myCollection.toJSON();
var serializedString = JSON.stringify(json);
```

To restore the collection, reverse the steps:

1. `JSON.parse` to convert the raw string to a JSON object
2. [`collection.reset`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) to convert the JSON object to a collection

[Here's a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/c7kSh/1/)

```
// setup test collection
var collection = new Backbone.Collection();
collection.add(new Backbone.Model({ hello: "world" }));

// serialize it to a string
var json = collection.toJSON();
var serialized = JSON.stringify(json);
console.log(serialized);

// get it back
var json2 = JSON.parse(serialized);
var collection2 = new Backbone.Collection();
var restored = collection2.reset(json2);

// check that it worked
console.log(restored.at(0).get("hello"));
```

​

Comment: fantastic!  thank you, you rock!  This is exactly what I needed to know :-)  Now ontop the next part of this little project :-)